# Rearrange character column using "PROC FORMAT" in SAS

Tags: format, sas

I want to take the follow data variable:

```
"Nebraska-Iowa"
"Washington-Arkansas"
"Illinois-Utah"
```

and transform it so that it orders the character groups around the hyphen to be in alphabetical order:

```
"Iowa-Nebraska"
"Arkansas-Washington"
"Illinois-Utah"
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I need to split the string around the hyphen, rearrange if necessary, and than paste back together.

**UPDATE**

After playing with Matthew's answer, I have decide to generalize this for any number of states with the following dataset:

```
Nebraska-Iowa
Washington-Arkansas-Texas
Illinois-Utah
Colorado
```

Here is the code I am trying to build. What I am struggling with is building an array that I loop through, pull out the appropriate word, and then pasting them back together after arranging. Please help!

```
/*Example dataset*/
data have;
    format text $50.;
    input text;
    datalines;  
Nebraska-Iowa
Washington-Arkansas-Texas
Illinois-Utah
Colorado
run;

/*Rearrange strings in dataset*/
data arrangestrings;
    set have;
    length result $50;
    howmanyb = countc(text,'-');
    howmany = howmanyb + 1;
    array state[howmany] _character_;
    do i=1 to howmany;
         state[i] = scan(text, i, '-');
    end;
    call sortc(of state(*));
    result = catx("-", state[*]);
    keep result;
run;
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using to try to accomplish this.

Comment: I am new to SAS and not sure how to begin outside of applying a user-defined format to a data set. If you could offer some advice or point me in a direction, it would be very helpful.

Comment: My suggestion would be to search on google/etc. how to do this ("User defined format SAS") and then come back with questions you have.

Comment: I have done that, but it hasn't helped me get closer to the specific formatting I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: How about this.  Get a dataset with "start" being the thing you want to change, "label" being what you want to change it to.  Try to make that dataset.  If you can't get it to work, edit the question with what you're trying.  If you can, but don't know how to move from there, again, edit with that.

Comment: @Joe, please see the updated question and let me know if you have any advice.

Comment: Stu, the problem with using arrays to solve the more general problem is that in SAS the array size must be known at compile time.   Thus, you can't use `howmany` to define the array.  Because there are only 50 states, you could define the state array using `array state[50] $50`.  Last I checked, the only dynamic storage option that SAS offers is the hash object (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1b4cbtmb049xtn1vh9x4waiioz4.htm).  You could implement this via a hash object rather than an array, but it would probably be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Also, the built-in variable `_character_` stands for all character variables defined in the PDV (program data vector), which is not what you want here.

Comment: Thanks. That's too bad about dynamic storage options. I was using states for simplicity, but really it is going to be lists of chemo drugs, of which there is no well defined table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to go to the trouble of defining a user-defined format for a task like this.  The built-in `scan` method is your friend here:

```
data have;
    format text $50.;
    input text;
    datalines;  
Nebraska-Iowa
Washington-Arkansas
Illinois-Utah
run;


data want;
    set have;
    length word1 word2 result $50;
    word1 = scan(text, 1, '-');
    word2 = scan(text, 2, '-');
    result = ifc(word1 <= word2, text, catx('-', word2, word1));
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Check out the documentation on the built-in functions that I used (`scan`, `ifc`, `catx`) if you're not familiar with them:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/allprodslang/67244/HTML/default/viewer.htm#syntaxByType-function.htm

Comment: Thanks, I am now trying to generalize it for when there are 1 for more than 2 states listed. I am going to update question with my attempt.